# How to include, downloaded jar from plugin wget as dependency in Maven project

Tags: java

I have a Jar in a remote location. I can download it to my src/lib using com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin. I want to use this jar in my code as a dependency to resolve compile error.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wget</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>http://remoteMachine/file/hello.zip</url>
                        <unpack>true</unpack><outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../src/lib</outputDirectory>                           
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>                                           
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a repo pointing to your jar

```
<repository>
    <id>cool project</id>
    <name>My cool repo</name>
    <url>file://${dirWithProject}/libs</url>
</repository>
```

Then just add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>yourGroupUd</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Another way is using `mvn install:install-file`

Or add the dependency like this

```
 <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>ldapjdk</groupId>
         <artifactId>ldapjdk</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\ldapjdk.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

source http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_external_dependencies.htm

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use `maven install` pointing to the jar storing on your file system, 
and in pom use it as the regular dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Jar resides in a remote machine so i don't think i can use mvn install pointing to the jar

Comment: But you were going to download it with wget, weren't you?

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently attempting to do is against the Maven conventions. If you use custom plugins to randomly unpack ZIPs you will most likely break some of the Maven features e.g. parallel execution with `-T` flag. Worst, by going against conventions you make your build harder to understand and loose the biggest benefit of Maven, [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).

Convert your ZIP into a proper Maven dependency and use standard dependency resolution mechanism, `<dependency>` section in `pom.xml`.